# How to login in JIRA using REST API and POST issue

Tags: java, rest

Actually my task is to post bug in JIRA from an Excel sheet.

Now I am able to post bugs in Bugzilla. Please any one help me with Java code about how to login and post bug using REST API. I have an example in perl, I would like it in java.

I tried with the following code, I'm able to login but now I would like to perform all tasks using JIRA REST API.

```
HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://id.atlassian.com/login?continue=https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa&application=jac");

    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "sxxxxxxx@live.com"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "xxxxxxxxxn"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("csrfToken", xcrfTokenVal));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("continue", "https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/Dashboard.jsp"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("application", "jac"));

    httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));

       response = httpclient.execute(httpost);

    System.out.println("Response " + response.toString());
     entity = response.getEntity();
            //System.out.println("Double check we've got right page " + EntityUtils.toString(entity));
    System.out.println("Response from : " + response.getStatusLine());
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to do a POST to "http://JIRA_URL/rest/auth/1/session", set a Cookie with the JSessionID to do other requests. In Jersey, basically you would do:

```
jsonParameters = "{\"username\":\"usernameValue\", \"password\": \"passwordValue\"}";
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://<JIRA_URL>/rest/auth/1/session");
ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, jsonParameters);
```

In the response you will have the JSessionID, so you have to save this in a Cookie and use it. In Jersey:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie;
...
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(jsession.getName(), jsession.getValue());
response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).cookie(cookie)
                .post(ClientResponse.class, jsonParameters);
```

JIRA Rest Doc:

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/6.3.1/#d2e3131